# Skip Rows in Data Source(CSV) in MSTest

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest

I am creating an Automated data-driven GUI testing project for my .Net WebApp using MSTest and Selenium. I am using CSV file as a data source for the test methods. The WebApp has multiple user level and currently I am maintaining different csv files for different user levels. This is not feasible when scaling and adding new test methods.

I want the CSV file to be divided in different sections as per the user rows e.g

```
#Admin
Row1
Row2

#Client
Row1
Row2
```

Is there any way that when Datasource is reading the data, it starts the data reading according to a specified user level? I have only stared coding a couple months ago and if there is any better way to achieve this, I am all ears.